# Transparent texture over colored polygon?

Tags: unity, blender, 3dsmax

Let's say I have a cube with each face having a different colour. I want them all to look like brick walls, but I don't want to have to recreate the same brick texture for every colour.

Is it possible to create a greyscale semi-transparent brick texture that I can overlay overtop of the polygon colour?

This scene will eventually be used in Unity, but I also have access to 3DS Max and Blender. So, whatever works.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `renderer.material.color` of the object to the color you want?

Comment: I'm just starting out with Unity, so I haven't gotten into scripting yet. Is there a GUI way to do it?

Comment: sure, in the scene simply click on the GameObject to which you have assigned the desired material, then click on _main color_ to edit color that will be combined with the texture.
You will find more information [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html)

Comment: Wow. So simple! Thank you! Copy that info into an answer, so that I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a material's diffuse color with a diffuse map in two ways:

1. In code, by setting the GameObject's `renderer.material.color' to a different one
2. Through the GUI by selecting the GameObject and in the inspector choosing the desired color in the *main color* field of the assigned material component

More information on Unity's materials can be found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html)